# CSS3 Gradient shows wrong colors in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, colors, generator, gradient

I created the following gradient using the Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator. It displays correctly in any browser except for IE (I've tested it in IE7, IE8, and IE9). In most browsers, the gradient is green. In IE, the gradient is blue and black. Any ideas why? I haven't tampered with the code since it was generated.

```
        background: #104815; /* Old browsers */
        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #104815 0%, #92b692 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#104815), color-stop(100%,#92b692)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #104815 0%,#92b692 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #104815 0%,#92b692 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #104815 0%,#92b692 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #104815 0%,#92b692 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#104815', endColorstr='#92b692',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Here's a screenshot using NetRenderer, showing the blue-to-black gradient in IE8:

[image]

Comment: It shows green for me in all versions of IE. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F9wY7/1/ . I’ve also removed the -ms- property, as IE 10 final was released without prefix, so it is not needed.

Comment: That's strange. IE must be messed up my computer. Thanks for looking into it for me.

Comment: Actually, I just tested in with NetRenderer in IE8 (see screenshot above), and I'm still getting the blue to black gradient, so there's clearly something going on.

Comment: must be a different issue on the site,as the jsfiddle shows the code as it is works correctly. I can't see any logical reason why the colours would change. Do you have a link to the page itself?

Comment: I've found the issue. IE9 and below are using the filter you provide. But for the colour values, the quotes are being escaped (by your server I guess) as &#039; When the colour values in the filter are pre and postfixed by &#039; the error handling is making a different colour. If you remove these it works correctly. You can try that on in the F12 tool.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I removed the quotes, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Great. I‘ll provide it as an answer, so this issue can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes for the colour values in the filter property are being encoded as '. This causes the colour to rely on error handing and changes the original value.

Fixing the quotes will give the correct green gradient.

Comment: Just FYI to anyone else who may come upon this problem, I was experiencing this problem with a Wordpress site. So evidently quotation marks must be removed from CSS3 gradient code when using Wordpress.